# linux bash greater than code -gt giving error [: too many arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

trying to execute a script

```
echo "count $count"   <!--  getting printed as count 10 --->

if [ $count -gt 0 ]
then
   echo "Greater than 0"
else
   echo "Less than 0"
fi
```

When I execute this script in my linux test environment it works absolutely fine without errors . When I try to execute in production linux environment i throws errors in the if code line mentioning **[: too many arguments**. Can anybody help me out with this.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Whats the value of `$count`?

Comment: maybe 10 , must be a value

Comment: And have you checked the value of the variable?

Comment: absolutely, just above the if code i am getting my value printed as 10 which I received by executing a count(*) query on database

Comment: Try replacing single square brackets with double square brackets.

Comment: Have a closer look what is **really** inside count, by doing a `echo -n "$count"|od -cx` before.

Comment: after doing echo -n "$count"|od -cx  i get        0000000  \t       1
           2009    0031
0000003.......what does itmean?

Comment: @Rajeshwar, `od` is for `octal dump` but allows also to dump in hexa, the output shows count contains a tab character, then a space, then the character 1, `printf "\t 1" | od -cx` gives the same result

Answer (score 3):

You `$count` likely contains something more than just a number in production. You can print it to debug, but you can also wrap it in quotes to make sure it's only one word. If you quote it:

```
[ "$count" -gt 0 ]
```

you may get a:

```
bash: [: foo: integer expression expected
```

error instead.

You get the original "too many arguments" error in cases like this, where you have extra options by accident:

```
$ [ -n 0 -gt 0 ]
[: too many arguments
```

You can also run the script using `bash -x path/to/script` to find out exactly what is it that bash sees / is executing.

Answer (score 0):

From comments, it seems IFS variable was changed to space for example
The following command reproduces the error

```
(IFS=' ';count=$'\t 1';[ $count -gt 0 ])
```